# Angular JS uigrid getting selected row ids

Tags: angular-ui-grid

```
onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) { 
    $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
    gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope, function (rows) {
        $scope.selectedComponents = gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows();
    });
},
```

how to get a list of all row id's from `$scope.selectedComponents` (each row has a `ID` Column)

the Web Api accepts a `List<int>` of `int` as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The [getSelectedRows](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.selection.service:uiGridSelectionService) function gives you the array of the row entities. You can build an array of yourself.

```
var idArray = $scope.selectedComponents.map(function(a) {return a.id;});
```

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)